# How to reset base attributes Skyrim

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, mods

Question: is it possible to reset base attributes in Skyrim, or otherwise set them to a specific value (eg via the console)?

Background: I installed a couple of mods on Skyrim that lower attributes if you don't eat/sleep (No Rest for the Wicked and The Belly Rules the Mind). Both very good mods and I used them for a while.

I started a new game and decided to disable the mods. However, I stupidly waited until I needed food/rest before disabling them.

After disabling the mods and reloading the game, I noticed my attributes were all red and 10 points lower than they should be.

I tried reinstalling the mod, sleeping, eating, etc., but the values now seem to be stuck lower than they should be.

Comment: Viewed 10,000 times... upvoted once. Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct answer is to use `player.setav`. `player.modav` is used for temporary improvements or diminishments and therefore will turn that stat red or green forever.

```
player.setav magicka 100
player.setav health 100
player.setav stamina 100
```

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer looking through Nexus and http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Console.  Running the following console commands fixed my attributes.  I was then able to remove the mod and continue playing as normal:

```
player.modav magicka 10
player.modav health 10
player.modav stamina 10
```